# Automate web search without API

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-search

I'm trying to automatically pull information from this [website](http://ports.com/sea-route/) for a set of values. I have a list of start and destination ports e.g. `THEODOSIA` and `KERCH` and I need to extract the calculated distance, speed and days for each start-destination combination. Can someone please advise on how to achieve this in Python? Another *potential* hurdle is that the ports in my list have 'short names' e.g. `THEODOSIA` which stands for `Port of Theodosia, Ukraine`. When you enter `THEODOSIA` in the search the website offers an auto-complete suggestion so that's fine for a manual search. However, I'm not sure how that works in automated searches.

I'm completely inexperienced in web scraping/searching so started writing the below code after reading a few online articles but have reached a dead end and don't think my code is of any use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import requests

#Example start and destination port values
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartPort':['THEODOSIA', 'ROSTOV'], 'DestinationPort':['KERCH', 'MARSEILLE']})

r = requests.get('http://ports.com/sea-route/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.findAll('tr', {"class": "span-7 prepend-top"})

startport = []
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':"span-7 prepend-top"}):
    startport=a.find('div', attrs={'class':"span-7 title ac_input"})
```

Comment: Why is Selenium tagged in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their API to get full port names. Then use these names to obtain distance, speed and days at sea.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


from_ = 'Theodosia'
to_ = 'Kerch'

find_port_url = 'http://ports.com/aj/findport/'
route_url = 'http://ports.com/aj/sea-route/'

def find_port(port_name):
    return requests.get(find_port_url, params={'q': port_name, 'limit': 1}).text.split('|')[0]

def find_route(f, t):
    data = requests.get(route_url, params={'a':0, 'b':0, 'c': f.split(',')[0], 'd': t.split(',')[0]}, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}).json()
    return data['cost']['nauticalmiles'], data['default_speed'], data['days_at_sea']


f = find_port(from_)
t = find_port(to_)

nm, speed, days = find_route(f, t)
print('Distance: {} nm Speed: {} Days at sea: {:.1f}'.format(nm, speed, days))
```

Prints:

```
Distance: 70 nm Speed: 10 Days at sea: 0.3
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll try this out for all the ports in my dataframe. Hopefully there's no limit on using the API and I don't need to pay to run my larger dataset!

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find out the `find_port_url` and `route_url` from?

Comment: @Python_newbieash I observed the URLs in Firefox developer tools -> Network tab. There are all requests that the page is making. Chrome has something similar.